# Form square mesh form one geo coordinate

Tags: php, geolocation, coordinates, coordinate-systems

I want to divide city into square zones. So suppose I give some Latitude,Longitude pair I need the Latitude,Longitude of point 1km right and below it to make a mesh of 1km width/hight square.

Comment: Show the code that you've tried

Comment: i tried varying y coordinate for right side 1km.thats it